# Orchid Tracking software - how to convert decimal values to GPS Degrees/minutes/seconds

Tags: gps, integer, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I'm looking at a system which saves Longitude/Latitude in Integer format.
It is called Orchid tracking software.

I do not know how to convert these integer values into degrees/minutes/seconds.
I first divide it by a million, but after that some other conversion is needed in order to get degrees/minutes/seconds

Is there a standard for Tracking units which save Long/Lat in integers to convert it to degrees/minutes/seconds?

Comment: please post some example values, and if possible approximatley where they have been recorded (latitude, longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to represent a lat/long coordinate  as integer:

1. decimal degrees * 1E6 (also called micro degrees)
2. decimal degrees * 1E7
3. milli angular seconds

1) and 2) are often used.

So first find out how they are represented, in case 1) and 2) you first convert them to decimal degrees. (e.g 48123456 => 48.123456). 
You know that longitude is in range [-180.0 , 180.0] and latitude from [-90.0, 90]

Then it is simple to convert from decimal degrees (DEG) to Degrees Minutes Seconds (DMS) Just look up wiki, or the answer from njzk2.
But beware i am not sure if his answer did handling of special cases when rounding errors lead to situation when second 59.999999 becomes to 60.0 = 0, in that case the minute has to be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

degrees/minute/seconds is simply the number of seconds displayed in base 60.

Assuming Orchid tracking software does use seconds, you can transform `value` this way:

```
seconds = value mod 60
minutes = (value / 60) mod 60
degrees = (value / (60*60))
```

However, if the values are in millionth of degree :

```
degrees = integer part of (value / 1000000)
minutes = integer part of (((value - degrees * 1000000) * 60) / 1000000)
seconds = integer part of (((value - degrees * 1000000 - minutes * 1000000 / 60) * 60 * 60) / 1000000)
```

or, you can convert millionth of degree to seconds :

```
total_seconds = value * 60 * 60 / 1000000
```

and apply the first formulas.

Comment: hi, this is great help thanks, I'm thinking that it uses seconds, as if i take the values initially and divide it by a million, the Integer part (degrees) is not between 90 and -90. When I use the top formula for degrees ((value / (60*60))) I get a large value >30 000 for the degree. Should I do something else to this value in order to get to the degrees please?

Comment: can you post example values for known places, so we can understand what format it is?